# Problem writing to a database on iphone in mobile safari

Tags: sqlite, web-applications, mobile-safari

I have got a web app working in Safari 5 on the desktop that writes to a local storage database - not problems!  Able to add, update and delete records fine.

I then set the web app up on the iphone, but it seems to be ignoring all database transcattions except creating and dropping tables.

It does not matter whether the app is on line or off line. If I add a record, it does not get added to the database.  I enabled the debug console, but there are no error messages.

The instruction to add the record just seems to be ignored!  It doesn't matter which page of the app i am on and I have made sure that only the index file has a link to the manifest...

Suggestions would be very welcome!!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

OK... Thanks if you looked at this...

:)

Turns out that when the app was locally cached, the page refreshes were happening too quickly for the data to be added to the database!

I have added some settimeout's and all is peachy...

Sorry to anyone who went for it...

:)